# An array of 5 string is given where each string contains 2 characters, Now you have to sort these strings using insertion sort, like in a dictionary

Tags: arrays

An array of 5 string is given where each string contains 2 characters, Now you have to sort these strings using insertion sort, like in a dictionary.

Input
Input contains 5 strings of length 2 separated by spaces.
String contains only uppercase English letters.

Output
Print the sorted array.

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
function easySorting(arr)
  {
    let n = arr.length;
        for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            // Choosing the first element in our unsorted subarray
            let current = arr[i];
            // The last element of our sorted subarray
            let j = i-1; 
            while ((j > -1) && (current < arr[j])) {
                arr[j+1] = arr[j];
                j--;
            }
            arr[j+1] = current;
        }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).